# $virtualFields, CakePHP, get variables

Tags: cakephp

I have this in my Model:

```
public $virtualFields = array(
        'distance' => '( 3959 * acos( cos( radians(40.722803) ) * cos( radians( Note.latitude ) ) * cos( radians( Note.longitude ) - radians(-73.591082) ) + sin( radians(40.722803) ) * sin( radians( Note.latitude ) ) ) )'
    );
```

And in my Controller:

```
$data = $this->Note->find('all', array('fields' => array('distance'), 'conditions' => array('distance <' => 1)));
```

This works great.. but now I'd like to actually pass my get variables $lat and $lng in to the correct areas in the virtual field from my controller.  I thought this would be straight forward but I can't figure it out!

Answer (score 3):

As far as I know, virtual fields weren't designed to deal with that, since your variables are actually constants from the point of view of the database.

I'm not sure if this works, but you could try to redefine the virtual field before calling `Model::find`:

```
// Controller code
$this->Note->virtualFields = array(
    'distance' => "( 3959 * acos( cos( radians($lat) ) * cos( radians( Note.latitude ) ) * cos( radians( Note.longitude ) - radians($lng) ) + sin( radians($lat) ) * sin( radians( Note.latitude ) ) ) )"
);
$data = $this->Note->find('all', array('fields' => array('distance'), 'conditions' => array('distance <' => 1)));
```

If it works, you'll probably want to create a model method to do that, instead of polluting the Controller...

Comment: Yep, this is the way to it (and similar to how I do it). I would suggest merging the existing `$virtualField` var so you don't lose ones you already defined, and also throwing this in maybe `beforeFind` on the note model.

Comment: Maybe consider doing the calculation with PHP in afterFind()? Could be worth profiling...